# .sass syntax & color colding with Dreamweaver

Tags: css, syntax, sass, dreamweaver

I've been trying to use Dreamweaver and Sass. I'd rather speed up my coding by using .sass, but DW is not recognizing the color coding....everything stays pink. When using .scss, everything is fine. but it does not like the no brackets, no semi-colons so it keeps everything pink. Any solution to this?

P.S. I've already updated the two files to add the extensions.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't switch to a better code editor like say [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)?

Comment: I'm just use to DW. But I just bought sublime and watched some tutorials and now it feels a lot better coding. I guess i'm good to go now. Also tried out brackets.io but it seems to be limited version and ripoff of sublime. Thanks

Comment: Oh yeah, i tried using a plugin, but it seems its incompatible with my version (CS6). Maybe it will help someone else who continues to use DW -
[link](https://github.com/adamcoulombe/dw-compass-codehints)